# Recommended books for movie poster design

Tags: resource-recommendations, posters

I was looking for some good **books** that can be used as a **reference and guide** while designing **movie posters**. Google gave me the names of some, but they're just movie poster collections.

What I'm looking for is not just tutorials, but books which give **informative & creative insights** into various **movie poster designing aspects, techniques, methods, theories** and **history**.

Which are the best books that fit in this category?

Comment: A few hundred posters per year, divided by handfuls of studios. So who has ever made many movie posters? How can write such a book with authority? Critics might rate or compare posters but will not have much to offer about making new posters. Maybe extend your search to book about posters in general or even magazine-title-pages (one dominant illustration and limited text) - as you are hunting for "aspects" and "theories" you might be able to transfer concepts to the movie context.

Answer (score 1):

It is not specifically about movie posters, but about book design in itself.
Well, it is also a great approach to building compositions of any sort, IMHO.

The book is "The form of the book", by Jan Tschichold.

Answer (score 1):

After numerous search, I recently found a book titled **Selling the Movie: The Art of the Film Poster** written by Ian Haydn Smith, editor of film magazines Curzon and BFI. Haven't bought it yet. Saw some of its preview pages on Google Books and Amazon. My impression is that it pretty much fits my needs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any books that fit *exactly* your criteria. Two suggestions that may be close to what you are looking for:

Saul Bass: 20 iconic film posters

Wolfgang Weingart: My Way to Typography